# Motion/change detection in videostreaming with dynamic background

Tags: opencv, motion-detection

I wanna detect motion in videostream where background is in dynamic motion using OpenCV. So false positive result is generated such as tree is detected as moving object.
If I want to perform video stabilization and then motion/change detection then what approach ,shall I choose for motion/change detection??. Background subtraction and concept of frame differencing is not working since background is in dynamic motion. Since I am beginner in field of computer vision so I am not much aware about other techniques!

Any help from your end would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

After finding the contour generated by comparing two consecutive frames, you can use an `if` statement to specify the minimum area the contour needs to be in order for it to not be considered as background noise.

Comment: Thats! not working some countour has larger area then object....